# Flag a question for migration to unlisted StackExchange site

Tags: feature-request, migration

When I flag a question as more appropriate for another StackExchange site, I can only choose to move the question to ELL or meta.  Sometimes to question is more appropriate for workplace for StackOverflow.  Am I missing something?  Or is this something we can add?

Comment: Only the most common sites will get listed. It took *years* to get ELL on that list. If you think it should be migrated somewhere else, write a custom flag and a mod will consider it.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was the answer. :-(  I like the pre-formulated migration messages the OP will see, and the point-and-click movement.  It's strange, you'd think all the sites would be listed in a big blob underneath the popular ones.

Comment: @jimm101 There are many reasons why migration paths are limited, not least of them that the best target is not always obvious, and low-quality questions should be closed rather than migrated. The past discussions on the lack (until fairly recently) of an ELL migration are informative.

Answer (score 2):

> Only the most common sites will get listed. It took years to get ELL on that list. If you think it should be migrated somewhere else, write a custom flag and a mod will consider it. – curiousdannii Jan 11 at 23:48